# white screen after installed capacitor ionic apk in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I followed below steps to generate apk
npx cap add android
ionic capacitor build android --prod
npx cap sync
npx cap open android
in android studio I build apk but after install this,
It showing white screen not a home page